# How to get data with recursive query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to write query finding all cities reachable from city `Agat` by train with a maximum of 3 stops. I am trying to solve this but I keep getting errors, not sure how to write this better?

tables look like this

```sql
CREATE TABLE CITIES (
  CID int primary key,
  CITY varchar(50) default NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Trains (
  departure integer references Cities(cid),
  arrival integer references Cities(cid),
  railline varchar(255) default NULL,
  Tid integer primary key,
  Price integer default NULL
);
```

Here's the recursive query and Im getting this error

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer = character varying
LINE 6:   INNER JOIN trains t ON t.arrival = c.city
```

```sql
WITH recursive get_cities AS (
  SELECT 0 AS stops, city FROM cities WHERE city = 'Agat'
  UNION
  SELECT r.stops + 1 AS stops, c.city
  FROM cities c
  INNER JOIN trains t ON t.arrival = c.city
  INNER JOIN get_cities r ON r.city = t.departure AND r.stops < 3
)

select * from get_cities;
```

Comment: `cities.city` is a `varchar` (e.g. `'Paris'`)  but `trains.arrival` is an integer (e.g. `42`) - you simply can not compare those with `=`. You probably mean `t.arrival = c.cid`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some comments :

1. In the query, you have to refer to the `cid` column of table `city` instead of the `city` column
2. Optional : You can explicit the parameters of the recursive query (see the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-RECURSIVE)) : `WITH RECURSIVE get_cities (stops, city) AS ( ... )`
3. Optional : The condition to stop the recursive should be in the `WHERE` clause of the recursive term : `WHERE r.stops < 3`
4. Optional : I would suggest to inverse the order of the tables in the `JOIN` clause starting with `get_cities` for more readability

Try this :

```
WITH RECURSIVE get_cities (stops, cid) AS (
  SELECT 0, cid
    FROM cities 
   WHERE city = 'Agat'
UNION ALL
  SELECT r.stops + 1 AS stops, c.cid
    FROM get_cities r 
   INNER JOIN trains t ON t.departure = r.cid
   INNER JOIN cities c ON c.cid = t.arrival
   WHERE r.stops < 3
)
select * from get_cities;
```

**Update :**

With 2 different tables `Trains` & `Flights`, you have to `LEFT JOIN` both tables and then merge the results with `COALESCE` :

```
WITH RECURSIVE get_cities (stops, cid) AS (
  SELECT 0, cid
    FROM cities 
   WHERE city = 'Agat'
UNION ALL
  SELECT r.stops + 1 AS stops, c.cid
    FROM get_cities r 
    LEFT JOIN trains t ON t.departure = r.cid
    LEFT JOIN flights f ON f.departure = r.cid
   INNER JOIN cities c ON c.cid = COALESCE(t.arrival, f.arrival)
   WHERE r.stops < 3
)
select * from get_cities;
```

Comment: "*You have to explicit the parameters of the recursive query*" - no, that's not a requirement. If you leave out the column list after the `WITH()` the names will be derived from the column aliases in the first query of the UNION.

Comment: @Edouard I have one more question, how can I also merge another table with this? For e.g I have same table as `trains` named `flights`. I'd also want to count from there too

Comment: answer updated with the case of two tables `trains` & `flights`